# Generics and wildcards in static values. It says that is the same class but doesnt compile

Tags: java, generics, static, wildcard

```
public interface Moo<T> {
    T getValue();
}

public class Bar<T> {
}

public class Foo<T extends Moo<Long>> {
    private static Foo<?> foo;

    private Bar<T> bar;

    public Foo(Bar<T> bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    //getters and setters

    public void barfoo(List<T> list) {
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public void foobar(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.getValue());
    }

    public void other() {
        List<? extends Moo<Long>> somelist = null;
        foo.barfoo(somelist);
    }
}
```

It generates a error, says that I can't compile because `somelist` can't go in that function. Says "Required ? extends Moo<Long> found ? extends Moo<Long>"
I don't know why this happens, either how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarification, let's create an implementation of the `Moo` interface:

```
public class MooImpl implements Moo<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long getValue() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Getting back to your class, in the eyes of the compiler, the `static` member of type `Foo` has an **unknown** generic parameter, which means that at Runtime, this parameter can be replaced with *anything*. We can easily instantiate the `static` member with a `Foo` instance, parameterized by `MooImpl` (we're allowed to do so, because `MooImpl extends Moo<Long>`. We say that `MooImpl` is **a known subtype** of `Moo<Long>` at Compile-time.

Now let's take a look on the `other()` method. At Runtime, the `? extends Moo<Long>` may result in different type than the `T`, which is why the compiler gives you an error. It does so, because `? extends Moo<Long>` stands for an **unknown subtype** of `Moo<Long>`. This way it *differs* with the **known subtype** (`MooImpl`).

In order to make it work, we can change the parameter of the `barfoo()` method to `List<? extends Moo<Long>>`.

```
public class Foo<T extends Moo<Long>> {
    private static Foo<?> foo = new Foo<MooImpl>(new Bar<MooImpl>());

    private Bar<T> bar;

    public Foo(Bar<T> bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void barfoo(List<? extends Moo<Long>> list) {
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public void foobar(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.getValue());
    }

    public void other() {
        List<? extends Moo<Long>> somelist = null;
        foo.barfoo(somelist);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the trade off of this solution? Do you know something peculiar?

Answer (score 1):

Any instance of your class `Foo` will be created with a concrete type `T` that is extending `Moo<Long>`. The method `barfoo` requires an argument of type `List<T>` where this `T` is the exact same type from instantiation.

Now you call this method with a `List<? extends Moo<Long>>`. That `? extends Moo<Long>` is not the same as your type `T`. It could be any other subtype of `Moo<Long>`. So the compiler must reject this method call.